Approximating powers of elements on the unit circle
Let $R \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. We say that $R$ is adequate if:
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \; \; \forall \varepsilon > 0  \; \; \forall w \in S^1 \; \; \exists r\in R \; \; |w^n - w^r| < \varepsilon$$
where $S^1$ denotes the set $\{|w| = 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.
In words, given any $w \in S^1$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can approximate $w^n$ arbitrarily well by $\{w^r \}_R$. This is equivalently stated as defining that $R$ is adequate if and only if $\{w^n\}$ $\subseteq$ $\overline{\{w^r\}}$ for every $w \in S^1$. The study of such sets has become relevant to me in some of my work in complex analysis.
Question: Is there an accessible description of the adequate subsets $R \subseteq \mathbb{N}$?
Here are some elementary results I have proved.
We say that $R$ is perfect if it has every residue mod every base; that is to say, $\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}, \; \exists r \in R$ s.t. $r \equiv m\text{ mod }{n}$.
Lemma: If $R$ is adequate, then it is perfect.
Proof: Consider $e^{2 \pi i q}$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. $\square$
Lemma: If $R$ contains arbitrarily long stretches of consecutive integers, then it is adequate.
Proof (sketch): Let $R$ be as described. This is clearly sufficient for $w = e^{2 \pi i q}$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, let $w = e^{2 \pi i t}$ for $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.  By the pigeonhole principle, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0 < |w^N - 1| < \varepsilon$. Let $M >> N \varepsilon^{-1}$ and let $r_1, ..., r_M$ be a sequence of consecutive integers in $R$. Then, there exists $r \in \{ r_1, ..., r_M\} \subseteq R$ such that $|w^n - w^r| < \varepsilon$. $\square$
Corollary: $R$ need not have positive upper density.
I am interested in an answer to the question I stated, or failing that, any examples of such sets $R$ which anyone is able to construct which are non-trivial in the sense that they are not covered by the second lemma above -- or even any perfect sets which are not covered by the second lemma.
Edit: I found a perfect set which does not contain any consecutive integers (in fact, far from it). Consider:
$$(1!), (2!+1), (3!), (4!+1), (5!+2), (6!), (7!+1), (8!+2), (9!+3), (10!), ...$$
I hope the pattern is clear. I find it difficult to imagine that this set is adequate.

This seems maybe related to a "set of recurrence" in dynamical systems...?

@GregMartin Thanks for the comment, this definitely seems to resemble a dynamical system. Do you know any references for sets of recurrence?

Pattern for that last sequence wasn't super clear to me. Is it $(n+k)!+k$, with $0\le k<n$?

@VarunVejalla Not exactly what you wrote, I think. It is a little difficult to describe in closed form. It's $(n+1)! + a_n$, where $a_n = 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,...$ if that makes it clearer.

Another equivalent description of an adequate set is that it is perfect and ${w^r:r\in R}$ is dense in $S^1$ for all $w=e^{2\pi i x}$ with irrational $x$.

@VarunVejalla Yes, that is true – ${w^r}$ must avoid a segment of the circle. In some sense, this would intuitively suggest that it is quite unlikely that a subset $R$ is not adequate; I’d even conjecture that inadequacy is a measure zero set, given an appropriate probability distribution on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, but that might be a little too unsubstantiated.

There is also always the inverse problem: given a set $R$, for which $w \in S^1$ is it adequate?

@VarunVejalla Thanks for the ideas, Varun. Perhaps you could write them up briefly in an answer with sketch derivations? I was planning to do something similar myself, even though I am not close to a solution either.

Sure, I can write it up later today. I also thought a sufficient condition is if $R$ is perfect and $\forall\epsilon>0\forall w\in S^1\exists r\in R$ such that $|w^r-1|<\epsilon$, but I couldn't show that that's enough for $R$ being adequate. Have you found any (infinite) set that is perfect and you know for sure is not adequate?

@VarunVejalla The condition looks compelling, but I would guess that it's not enough. There is a real difficulty with this question that both finding (non-trivial) positive examples and negative examples is somehow very difficult. I'll think more about finding a counterexample of the type you describe. (By the way, every perfect set is automatically infinite.) Maybe I will need to learn more about dynamical systems to figure this out!

Deleted some of my earlier comments because I don't think it works out actually.

@GregMartin Indeed, $R$ is adequate in the sense of this question if and only if for all $k\in \mathbb Z$, the translate $R+k$ is a set of recurrence for all (not necessarily irrational) circle rotations.  (BTW, in this setting, topological recurrence is equivalent to measurable recurrence.)

Lemma: $R$ is adequate iff $R$ is perfect and $\forall x\in[0,1)\setminus\mathbb{Q}\;\exists (r_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\in R:\; (r_nx)_{n=1}^\infty$ is uniformly distributed (u.d.) mod 1.
Proof: For the forward direction, suppose $R$ is adequate. We already know it's perfect. Let $w=e^{2\pi i x}$ with $x\in[0,1)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Since $R$ is adequate and $x$ is irrational, $\{w^r:r\in R\}$ is dense in $S^1$, which then means $\{xr\pmod1:r\in R\}$ is dense in $[0,1)$. One way we can construct a good $(r_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is by a greedy strategy, as if we're identifying $(r_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ one item at a time, and picking them to make $(r_nx\pmod 1)$ sufficiently spread out.
For the reverse direction, suppose $R$ is perfect and the condition holds. Let $w=e^{2\pi i x}$. We want to show that $\{w^r:r\in R\}$ is dense in $S^1$. Since the relevant sequence $(r_nx)$ for $x$ is u.d. mod 1, we see that $\{w^{r_n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $S^1$. $\square$
This might seem like a trivial reframing of the problem, but it helps us use some existing theorems about uniformly distributed sequences (which were easier to find on Google than theorems about $\{w^r:r\in R\}$ being dense in $S^1$). For example, if $R$ is perfect and there is a polynomial $p\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that for all $x$ irrational, some coefficient is irrational as well when multiplied by $x$, with $p(n)\in R$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $R$ is adequate. If $R$ contains the primes, then $R$ is adequate.
Moreover, we see that it's hard to find a perfect set that is not adequate. This is because the sequence $(a_nx)$ is u.d. mod 1 for almost all real $x$ when $(a_n)$ is a sequence of distinct integers (as it will be in our case when each term is an element of $R$).
I got a lot of this from chapter 1 of "Uniform Distribution of Sequences" by L. Kuipers and H. Niederreiter. There are more criteria there that may be helpful.

Fantastic answer. I was about to add a substantial improvement to my answer along similar lines which uses the ergodic theorem, but I think I made an error in my reasoning. But this is definitely the "right" approach to this question, and more or less answers the question, seeing as the analysis of u.d. mod 1 is probably an open research question. It would be great to find more examples of sufficient sets; I'll read the text you mentioned. Where did you hear about uniformly distributed sequences? I've never come across them previously.

I wouldn't say this fully answers the question. It's a bit different than just understanding u.d. mod 1, since you a) need to have $(r_nx){n=1}^\infty$ u.d. mod 1 for all irrational $x$ but b) $(r_n){n=1}^\infty$ can be different for different $x$. Try asking on MathOverflow - you might get better references to existing literature there. And I'm not sure where I first heard about uniformly distributed sequences, but I think they do come up frequently with problems like this, since $(nx)_{n=1}^\infty$ is u.d. mod 1 iff $x$ is irrational.

Not fully, but it gets a lot closer than I predicted while asking the question, and as I said, I expect (perhaps wrongly) that what's left over is more or less the frontiers of research. That $(a_nx)$ is u.d. mod 1 for almost all $x$ is more than enough for me to accept the answer. Thanks for the help.

@J.S. Do you mind if I ask on MathOverflow? You got me invested in this question now!

No problem! I would be intrigued to know the full solution (but I think that question you asked on fractional parts is more interesting, personally).

Re: nontrivial examples.  Following on Varun's answer, examples of adequate sets include those given by Hartman uniformly distributed sequences.  These sequences $(r_n)$ satisfy the stronger condition that for every $t\in (0,2\pi)$, $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \exp(ir_nt)=0$.  Integer sequences with polynomial growth and no obvious congruence obstructions are often Hartman uniformly distributed.  These include $(\lfloor n^{5/2}\rfloor)$, more generally $(\lfloor n^c \rfloor)$ where $c>0$, $c\notin \mathbb N$, integer parts of polynomials such as $(\lfloor \sqrt{2}n^5 + 7n\rfloor)$, and some specific sequences of superpolynomial growth, such as $(\lfloor \exp((\log n)^c)\rfloor)$ for $1<c<3/2$.  See Máté Wierdl's thesis or the article by Nair linked below for details.
Unfortunately the concept of Hartman uniform distribution goes by many names in the literature, making it difficult to do a comprehensive search.  Often such sequences are called "ergodic averaging sequences" or "ergodic sequences", e.g. in Section 4 of this article by Bergelson and Ferré Moragues.
A weaker condition than $R$ having a Hartman-u.d. sequence of elements is $R$ being dense in the Bohr topology of $\mathbb Z$.  The Bohr topology of $\mathbb Z$ is the weakest topology making all homomorphisms $\chi:\mathbb Z\to S^1$ continuous.  Every such homomorphism has the form $\chi(n)=w^n$ for some $w\in S^1$, so a neighborhood base for $n_0$ in the Bohr topology is given by sets of the form $Bohr(n_0;w_1,\dots,w_d;\varepsilon):=\{n\in \mathbb Z: \max_{j\leq d} |w_j^n-w_j^{n_0}|<\varepsilon\}$, where $d\in \mathbb N$, $w_j\in S^1$, and $\varepsilon >0$.  To verify that  $R$ being dense in the Bohr topology implies $R$ is adequate, note that $R$ is adequate if and only if for all $w\in S^1$, $\varepsilon>0$, and $n_0\in \mathbb Z$, $R\cap Bohr(n_0;w;\varepsilon)$ is nonempty.
After digesting the definitions, one naturally wonders whether every set $R$ which is dense in the Bohr topology admits a Hartman uniformly distributed sequence of elements.  Furstenberg asked Katznelson whether this is so, and Katznelson published a counterexample in his article "Sequences of integers dense in the Bohr group."  Unfortunately this article is difficult to find online, but his construction is examined in detail in Section 5b of the article by Badea, Grivaux, and Matheron linked below.  Saeki found a different construction, also linked below.
Nonexamples: an increasing sequence is lacunary if $\inf_{n\in \mathbb N} r_{n+1}/r_n > 1$.  Lacunary sequences are never adequate - see the articles by Pollington and/or Katznelson, and their references.
(Edit: For examples of sets which are far from being dense in the Bohr topology, see the papers by Dressler and Pigno, and by Kunen and Rudin.)
Badea, Catalin; Grivaux, Sophie; Matheron, Étienne, Rigidity sequences, Kazhdan sets and group topologies on the integers, J. Anal. Math. 143, No. 1, 313-347 (2021). ZBL1476.11062.
Katznelson, Y., Chromatic numbers of Cayley graphs on (\mathbb Z) and recurrence, Combinatorica 21, No. 2, 211-219 (2001). ZBL0981.05038.
Nair, R., On uniformly distributed sequences of integers and Poincaré recurrence, Indag. Math., New Ser. 9, No. 1, 55-63 (1998). ZBL0922.11064.
Pollington, Andrew D., On the density of sequences ({n_k\xi}), Ill. J. Math. 23, 511-515 (1979). ZBL0401.10059.
Saeki, Sadahiro, Bohr compactification and continuous measures, Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 80, 244-246 (1980). ZBL0453.43005.
Dressler, Robert E.; Pigno, Louis, The Haar measure of certain sets in the Bohr group, Colloq. Math. 41, 297-301 (1979). ZBL0445.10044.
Kunen, Kenneth; Rudin, Walter, Lacunarity and the Bohr topology, Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 126, No. 1, 117-137 (1999). ZBL0915.43003.

Thanks, John, this is an excellent answer. The Bohr topology sounds quite fascinating, and I'll be trying to read some of these articles in the next few weeks. The remark on lacunary sequences is, of course, reminiscent of the theory of power series in complex analysis, which is where this question arose for me. With analogy to such a theorem, do you know off the top of your head if every sequence of naturals with $\liminf_k n_k = 1$ is dense in the Bohr topology?

Even that corollary that sequences of the form $(\lfloor n^c \rfloor)$ are perfect alone is staggering.

I added a couple of references at the end of the answer for examples of sets that are far from being dense in the Bohr topology.  Kunen and Rudin in particular prove that when $p$ is an integer valued polynomial of degree 2 or 3 then ${p(n):n\in \mathbb Z}$ is not dense in the Bohr topology, and in fact its closure in the Bohr compactification has Haar measure 0.

Thanks for these references; I note in this comment that this example answers the question in my first comment (where I meant to write $\liminf_k n_k^{\frac{1}{k}}$) in the negative.

This is clearly a difficult question which will likely take at least some time to be resolved. In this answer, I will document any progress I make towards a solution.
Lemma: If $R$ is perfect and contains arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions, then it is adequate.
Proof: This is a straightforward generalisation of the last lemma in the main post. Since $R$ is perfect, we reduce to the case where $w = e^{2 \pi it}$ for $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. We recall that for each $w \in S^1$,  there exists $N(w)$ such that $|w^{N(w)} - 1| < \varepsilon$. The pigeonhole principle in fact grants something much stronger. For any $z \in S^1$, let $N(w,z)$ be minimal for the constraint $|w^{N(z,w)} - z| < \varepsilon$. Then, by the pigeonhole principle, $(N(w,z))_{S^1 \times S^1}$ is uniformly bounded (by a constant which only depends on $\varepsilon$).
Let $N$ be a uniform upper bound of this form. By assumption, $R$ has an arithmetic progression of length $N$. Let the first term be denoted by $r_0$ and suppose the common difference is $d$. Then, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $k \in \{0,1,..., N \}$ such that:
$$|(w^d)^k -w^{n-r_0}| < \varepsilon$$
$$\iff |w^{r_0 + kd} - w^n| < \varepsilon$$
Therefore, there exists $r \in \{r_0, r_0 +d, ..., r_0 + Nd \} \subseteq R$ such that  $|w^r - w^n| < \varepsilon$. $\square$
